Uploading files via MS Graph SDK for .NET
I have been trying to follow the examples to upload large files for onedrive from Ms Graph SDK but I cannot seem to figure out where the DriveUpload object resides or what nuget package I need to install to make this work. My code is as follows:
        public async Task<Models.CloudStorage?> UploadFileByPathAsync(MemoryStream SourceFile, string DestinationPath, string RootFolderId = "")
    {
        if(RootFolderId == "")
        {
            RootFolderId = _armsFolderId;
        }

        using var stream = SourceFile;

        // Use properties to specify the conflict behavior
        // in this case, replace

        var uploadSessionRequestBody = new DriveUpload.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
        {
            Item = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" },
                },
            },
        };

        // Create the upload session
        // itemPath does not need to be a path to an existing item
        var uploadSession = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[RootFolderId].Root
            .ItemWithPath(DestinationPath)
            .CreateUploadSession
            .PostAsync(uploadSessionRequestBody);


        // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
        int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
        var fileUploadTask =
            new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, stream, maxSliceSize);

        var totalLength = stream.Length;
        // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
        IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {totalLength} bytes");
        });

        // Upload the file
        var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

        if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
        {
            var response = uploadResult.ItemResponse;
            Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ?
                $"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}" :
                "Upload failed");
        }

    }

The error I get over the conflit behavior is:
The type or namespace name 'DriveUpload' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cannot find much information online regarding where to add this. Also, I am trying to understand the performance differences between this large file upload vs the method indicated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I believe CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody is just part of the Microsoft.Graph namespace, you don't need the DriveUpload

I need to add the conflict behavior though and this is how they do it in the ms graph examples on the microsoft website. Could you provide an example of how to do this without it then but still have conflict behavior of replace?

You were correct remove DriveUpload allowed me to add the namespace specific to this item. Strange it works like that. MS docs are confusing for this reason alone. If you add this as an answer and put using Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession;
up top I will mark it as the answer.

Might be easier for you to answer your own question, as you have all the details and code to hand.

DriveUpload is a shorthand for namespace Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession. Therefore add:
using Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession;

And remove DriveUpload and it will work.
